# Invalid statement error in Oracle insert statement

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I am new to SQL. I have written procedure to save data in db. And from SQL I am trying to call the this procedure to save data. But getting SQL error > `ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement`. How can I resolve this error?

Here is my procedure:

```
PROCEDURE NEW_USER
(
    IN_CREATED_BY               IN VARCHAR2,
    IN_MODIFIED_BY                         IN VARCHAR2,
    IN_USERNAME                            IN VARCHAR2
)
AS
    L_USER_ID INTEGER;
    N_USER_ID  INTEGER := hibernate_sequence.NEXTVAL;
BEGIN
    SELECT case 
         when exists( SELECT USER_ID FROM T_MT_USER WHERE USERNAME = IN_USERNAME )
         then 
              (SELECT USER_ID FROM T_MT_USER WHERE USERNAME = IN_USERNAME)
         else 0
       end  into L_USER_ID
      FROM dual;
      
    IF (L_USER_ID = 0) THEN
    INSERT INTO T_MT_USER
    (USER_ID, ACCOUNT_EXPIRED_FLG, ACCOUNT_LOCKED_FLG, created_by, CREATED_TS, ACTIVE_FLG, end_effective_dt, modified_by, MODIFIED_TS, "password", password_expired, start_effective_dt, username) 
    VALUES
    (N_USER_ID, 0, 0, IN_CREATED_BY, SYSTIMESTAMP, 1, NULL, IN_MODIFIED_BY, SYSTIMESTAMP, '$2a$10$3hoAeeVJ0AG.CQS2xX8rT.wUlt1rjoiYsHW0YflZEiQ5QYzG4HpYi', 0, SYSTIMESTAMP, IN_USERNAME);
     END IF;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        log_api.fatal(log_ctx,'Exception in NEW_USER');
        RAISE;
END NEW_USER;
```

And my call in SQL:

```
USER_DEMO.NEW_USER('sbappi','sbappi','sumon5');
```

Comment: What gives you hibernate_sequence.NEXTVAL or what is this. Is it a Oracle  Sequence? Or same Hibernate staff?

Comment: this is for id. it is getting the id for the row

Comment: Which tool are you using to call the procedure? `sqlplus` requires an `execute` to run a stored procedure: `execute USER_DEMO.NEW_USER('sbappi','sbappi','sumon5');`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for your reply. it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by a_horse_with_no_name in above comment the following code is working fine for me >>>

```
execute USER_DEMO.NEW_USER('sbappi','sbappi','sumon5');
```